# Getting internal value with dot notation

Tags: python

I have a dictionary:

```
d = {'time': {36.0: 'mo'}, 'amount': {200.0: '$'}}
```

Each key (e.g. 'time') only ever has one value (e.g. {36.0 'mo'})

I'd like to access the 36.0 by doing

```
result = d.time
```

And the 200.0 by doing

```
result = d.amount
```

How do I do this? So far I have:

```
class Bunch(object):
  def __init__(self, adict):
    self.__dict__.update(adict)

x = Bunch(d)
print x.time
```

Which produces {36.0: 'mo'} not 36.0.

Comment: recursively change all `dict` values in `adict` to `Bunch` objects?  Although I don't see how you expect to get `'mo'` part if `d.time` just gives a key of a dictionary value that may (legally) have more then one pair.

Comment: You want to store *two* values in a variable/dictionary, yet get one "by default" when evaluating the variable? Sounds like you want a custom class and implement its `__str__` method or such.

Comment: And how would you like to access "mo" and "$"? Note that it can't be something like `d.time.unit`, because `d.time` evaluates to a float and floats don't have a `unit` attribute.

Comment: Why are the values structured as `{36.0: 'mo'}` instead of something like `(36.0, 'mo')`? They don't seem to be key-value associations.

Comment: [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) could be useful here.

Comment: Thanks all for comments. In answer: I'm not interested in getting "mo" or "$". This dict is from another source, I can't change it. I'm just trying to get an internal value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd subclass `dict` and override `__getattr__`, after having enshured that there is no name clash between the data keys and `dict` methods.

```
d = {'time': {36.0: 'mo'}, 'amount': {200.0: '$'}}

class Bunch(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        try:
            val = self[attr]
            return next(iter(val))
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError(attr)

x =  Bunch(d)
x.time # 36.0
```

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I've mentioned that in the answer

Answer (score 1):

Below snippet hijacks the attribute access, and returns the first key of the dict instead of the dict itself. It does this for all attributes except `__dict__`, so use accordingly and be aware of what this implies.

```
from __future__ import print_function                              

d = {'time': {36.0: 'mo'}, 'amount': {200.0: '$'}}

class Bunch(object):
  def __init__(self, adict):
    self.__dict__.update(adict)

  def __getattribute__(self, attr):
      if attr == '__dict__':
          return super(Bunch, self).__getattribute__(attr)

      return next(iter(self.__dict__[attr]))

x = Bunch(d)
print(x.time)
print(x.amount)
```

Testing it

```
➜  ~ python3 keys.py                                              
36.0
200.0
➜  ~ python2 keys.py                                              
36.0
200.0
```

Comment: this assumes python2, you can't do `.keys()[0]` in python 3

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen A possible edit could be `next(iter(self.__dict__['time']))`.

Comment: As a note, `next(iter(self.__dict__['time']))` should work in Python 2 and 3.

Comment: Thanks. However there are a LOT of these 'time', 'amount' keys. Hard-coding one line for each one is not practical or future-proof. I'm hoping there is a way to just do x.time (for example), without having to hard-code 'time' in my method. Any ideas?

Comment: @bakkal because you are updating `self.__dict__` you are placing those keys in the instance variables, so `__getattr__` would never be called.  You would need to override `__getattribute__` if you are going down that route. (or store the dict some other way)